# AG-GRID unable to add icon button into each row of the ag-grid and multiselection checkbox in my ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, ag-grid

In each row of my ag-grid. I need to add angular material icon button in each row of ag-grid. However, the outcome only shown me text button. It does not display me icon button in my ag-grid.

Next, I need to have multi selection checkbox in my ag-grid. However, in my ag-grid only able to select one row only. How can I achieve for multi selection row in ag-grid listing.

The following is my source code.

```
  constructor() { 
      this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
          paginationPageSize: 18,
          animateRows: true,
    };
      this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {
            field: "",
            width: 110,
            checkboxSelection: true
        },
        {
            headerName: "Distributor Code",
            field: "dist_code",
            width: 330,
            sortingOrder: ["asc", "desc"]
        },
        {
            headerName: "Distributor Name",
            field: "dist_name",
            width: 330,
            sortingOrder: ["asc", "desc"]
        },
        {
            headerName: "Status",
            field: "status",
            width: 330,
            sortingOrder: ["asc", "desc"],

        },
        {
            field: "", 
            width: 110, 
            cellRenderer: function clickNextRendererFunc(){
                    return '<button mat-stroked-button><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon></button>';
            }
        }
    ];
    this.gridOptions.rowData = [
        {dist_code: 1, dist_name: "ABC Enterprise", status: "Inactive"},
        {dist_code: 2, dist_name: "Go Go Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 3, dist_name: "Alibaba Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 4, dist_name: "Silver Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 5, dist_name: "George Enterprise", status: "Inactive"},
        {dist_code: 6, dist_name: "Kent Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 7, dist_name: "NP Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 8, dist_name: "ED Enterprise", status: "Inactive"},
        {dist_code: 9, dist_name: "DD Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 10, dist_name: "DF Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 11, dist_name: "JS Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 12, dist_name: "JD Enterprise", status: "Inactive"},
        {dist_code: 13, dist_name: "KFC Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 14, dist_name: "MCD Enterprise", status: "Inactive"},
        {dist_code: 15, dist_name: "AH Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 16, dist_name: "PP Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 17, dist_name: "KOH Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 18, dist_name: "HH Enterprise", status: "Active"},
        {dist_code: 19, dist_name: "GG Enterprise", status: "Inactive"},
        {dist_code: 20, dist_name: "PP2 Enterprise", status: "Active"}
    ]

    }
```

The following is my print screen 
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is having 3 parts.

***1. Enable multi-selection:***

You need to have this attribute on `ag-grid-angular` element: `rowSelection="multiple"`

***2. Enable selection checkbox:***

Keep `checkboxSelection: true` for the first `ColDef`, which you are already doing.

***3. Add angular material icon button in each row***

You need to use `cellRenderer` and return html string for this.

```
cellRenderer: (data) => {
    return `<mat-icon class="mat-icon material-icons mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true">
       home</mat-icon>`;
}
```

> Since `cellRenderer` expects html string in return, you should not simply provide `<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>` as it won't get compiled.

Comment: It should my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You are currently using the string as rendered, what you need is a component or you can use the custom class which handles it like [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#complex-cell-renderer-example). but, as you want to render the material component you will still have to compile the materialbutton.

I would suggest you to use the `cellRendererFramework` and use the custom component,
Create custom component called `RedComponentComponent` and render it like this.

```
cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,//your custom component
```

So, your cell will look like this

```
      {
        headerName: "Value",
        field: "value",
        cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
        width: 100
      },
```

And this component will have your button code, and it will be responsible for your rendering.

I forked their demo and it is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-wp7b99)  you can take a look.

Comment: @ChanYoongHon can you share your stackblitz

Comment: Worked for me! I use ag-grid-react, and this solution can be used in react project, too!

Comment: @Justcode-sir you tell me how to add multiple icon in each row in ag grid?

Comment: @Kapilsoni you mean like this? `<icon></icon><icon></icon>`

Answer (score 1):

try this approach:

```
 cellRenderer: params => {
          let eIconGui = document.createElement('span');         
            return  eIconGui.innerHTML = '<em class="material-icons">arrow</em>'  + ' ' + params.data.value;          
        }
```